# The ExecuteSQL processor doesn't work after connecting with other processor

Tags: apache-nifi

When I didn't connect any processors as an incoming one, the ExecuteSQL works perfectly fine as the screenshot

Screenshot#1

[image: 1]

But when I've connected with another processor, there's no flowfiles coming out of the ExecuteSQL processor.

Screenshot#2

[image: 2]

Anyone know how could I make it works? Thank you in advance :-)

Comment: Probably it goes to failed relation and you have terminated it.

Answer (score 0):

check the [NiFi docs](https://nifi.apache.org/docs.html) and you'll find this dscription

> Executes provided SQL select query. Query result will be converted to Avro format. Streaming is used so arbitrarily large result sets are supported. This processor can be scheduled to run on a timer, or cron expression, using the standard scheduling methods, or it can be triggered by an incoming FlowFile. If it is triggered by an incoming FlowFile, then attributes of that FlowFile will be available when evaluating the select query, and the query may use the ? to escape parameters. In this case, the parameters to use must exist as FlowFile attributes with the naming convention sql.args.N.type and sql.args.N.value, where N is a positive integer. The sql.args.N.type is expected to be a number indicating the JDBC Type. The content of the FlowFile is expected to be in UTF-8 format. FlowFile attribute 'executesql.row.count' indicates how many rows were selected.

it tells you that you have to use some special atrributes by triggering via flowfile.
something like `sql.args.1.type` and `sql.args.1.value`